# How to Show Value Of Button In TextBox With JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im Sorry If this is a easy question, i am new to Scripting and html and JQuery. I am trying to make it so when the 1 button is pressed that it will show the value in the box. I acheived it earlier with Get Element By Id but i am now trying it with Jquery and i am confused why my following code wont work. Thanks for any help!

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){
              var number1 = "1";
              $('#output').html(number1);
    });
  });
</script>

<body>

<input type="text"   id="output">

<input type="button" name="one" value = "1" id="button1"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get button value with jquery use `$("#button1").attr("value")` or `$("#button1").val()`

In your case to set value of input text use `$('#output').val($(this).attr("value"))`

The final code shoul be

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#button1').click(function(){
            $('#output').val($(this).val());
        });
  });
</script>

<body>

<input type="text"   id="output">

<input type="button" name="one" value = "1" id="button1"> 

</body>
</html>
```

[simple JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/gtbjn397/1/)

Comment: How is this fundamentally different then my answer...?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
          alert($('#output').val());
    });
});
```

I guess you kind of mixed up your mind. `#output` is the input in your code, so thats where you'd want to read the value from. If you want to print the value to another element you would have to append one and change the ids like so:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">Submit</button>
<span id="output"></span>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#button').click(function(){
             // Always use .text() if you dont need html output.
             $('#output').text($('#input').val());
       });
   });
</script>
```

---

Edit: it turns out I kinda mixed up my own mind ;) I see you want to output the value of the button that is clicked, simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#button1').click(function(e){
        // Either use $(this) or $(e.target).
        $('#output').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You might want to read [this article](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/04/this-and-this-in-jquery-callbacks/) on `this` and `$(this)` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){
              var value = $(this).val();
              $('#output').val(value);
    });
  });
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jqnynLbm/

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think you forgot to call jQuery. So add this on the header area--

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second, chenge the

```
$('#output').html(number1);
```

to

```
$('#output').val(number1); // use val because input tags contain value not html
```

And also if you want the value will come from the clicked button then you can use dynamically

```
$(this).val(); // this will handle the selector which is clicked by you and its value
```

and you can put this inside a variable as

```
var number1 = $(this).val();
```